# Variable not defined in If statement (Python, Ursina Module)

Tags: python, ursina

My problem is that when I change the content of the variable "XO" inside the if statement, the one in the condition of the If statement becomes undefined.

```
from ursina import *
import time
app = Ursina()
window.title = "Game"
window.borderless = False
window.exit_button_visible = False

XO = "X"

class Tile(Button):
    def __init__(self, position = (-5, -5, 0), texture = "assets/tile.png"):
        super().__init__(
            parent = scene,
            model = "quad",
            color = color.lime,
            position = position,
            texture = texture
        )
    def input(self, key):
        if self.hovered:
            if key == "left mouse down":
                if XO == "X":
                    Tile(position = self.position, texture = "assets/tile_x")
                    XO = "O"
                else:
                    Tile(position = self.position, texture = "assets/tile_0")
                    XO = "X"
                time.sleep(.005)
                destroy(self)
                
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        block = Tile((x-1, y-1))
app.run()
```

Comment: I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Comment: is there any error, if so you should post the full error message in your question? use [edit]

Comment: I believe the issue is that XO in the input function is a local variable, not the global variable defined above. Globals tend to be a bad idea as they lead can lead to unexpected behaviour that is difficult to debug. That said you should get the behaviour your expected by adding "global XO" as the first statement of the input function. Also, while Python does not enforce this, all capital variable names are by convention constants and should not be changed. Perhaps current_player would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue here is that you seem to be trying to reference a global variable inside of a some inner context. In general, this is not encouraged for a lot of reasons. One of the biggest in my opinion is that global code is difficult to maintain. Instead, I would encourage you refactor your code so that all of your code resides inside of a class, and work on encapsulating your code.

That being said, sometimes it is necessary to use the global scope. In order to do that, you simply use the `global` keyword before the name of the variable you want global scope for. In your case, you would simple do `global XO` at the start of your input function.