# How do I get the return value from a function?

Tags: python, ursina

How is it possible to get a return value from a function in a button?

What I would like to do is:

```
from ursina import *


app = Ursina()

def on_click():
    #Some code
    return #Some value

b = Button(on_click = on_click)

def input(key):
    if key == "left mouse down":
        print(b.returnvalue)

app.run()
```

but this obviously does not work.

Comment: No, but your `on_click` knows which button it was called for.  It can PUT something into `b`.

Comment: So, how do i do that?

Comment: Well, what do you want to do?  You can do `b.text = "Clicked!"` to change the text of the button, because `b` is a global.

Comment: Oohh... true, i forgot how that worked, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As detailed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68470036/variable-not-defined-in-if-statement-python-ursina-module), you can either declare a global variable before `on_click()`, and set that variable inside `on_click()` using the `global` keyword before the name of the variable.

It would be preferable however to create a class for your button, and create a member variable that you set inside an `on_click()` method and can later access with a getter method.

If you need a refresher on OOP concepts, I would recommend this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-oops-concepts/), or this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeznW_7DlB0&pp=ygUKcHl0aG9uIG9vcA%3D%3D).